# my service is not working after booting in SDK 23

Tags: android, android-service

iam trying to make my service working after Booting 
and its working in Versions less then 23

But bigger than that 
it doesnt work

```
my manifist
Permissions
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Reciever
        <receiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".BootReciever"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Service
        <service
            android:name=".Services.Azkar_Services"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
```

my Broadcast

```
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent Rec_Intent = new Intent(context, Azkar_Services.class);
        context.startService(Rec_Intent);

    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the category tag from your intent filter and make it like this

```
    <receiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".BootReciever"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and no need to add this as well

```
   <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Updated
this is my service code

```
public class Azkar_Services extends Service {
    public Azkar_Services() {
    }
    String[] Azkar;
    AzkarUtility azkarUtility;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Azkar =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Azkar);

        azkarUtility = new AzkarUtility(getApplicationContext(),Azkar);
        azkarUtility.Notification();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        azkarUtility.IsWorking[0] = false;
    }
}
```

and this is the class AzkarUtility

```
public class AzkarUtility {


    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private String[] Azkar_Array;
    Random mRandom;
    View mView;
    WindowManager mWindowManager;
    final boolean[] IsTouched = {false};
    public boolean[] IsWorking = {true};
    public AzkarUtility(Context context, String[] azkar_Array) {
        mContext = context;
        Azkar_Array = azkar_Array;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public String[] getAzkar_Array() {
        return Azkar_Array;
    }

    public void setAzkar_Array(String[] azkar_Array) {
        Azkar_Array = azkar_Array;
    }

    public void Notification(){

        if (IsWorking[0] == true)
        {
            new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    Notification();

                    Show_Elzekr();
                }
            }.start();
        }

    }

    private void Show_Elzekr() {


        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_zikr,null,false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.single_Zikr_Page_Textview);

        mRandom = new Random();

        int number = mRandom.nextInt(Azkar_Array.length - 1)+1;

        textView.setText(Azkar_Array[number]);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;
        mWindowManager.addView(mView,params);
        mView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                mWindowManager.removeView(mView);
                IsTouched[0] = true;
                return true;
            }
        });

        new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                if (IsTouched[0]==false)
                    mWindowManager.removeView(mView);
            }
        }.start();
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you granted all the permission's to application

Comment: ya and its working on sdk lower than 23 but bigger than 23 not working .... am i must ask for the permission if the version is more than or equal 23? or its not neccessary here

Comment: without getting permission your app won't work. Please make sure all the permission's are granted

Comment: so am i must ask for permission by making checking on the Build.Sdk.version so if it more than 23 i have to ask for permission ?

Comment: You must ask for permission weather the sdk is lower or higher than 23. so before anything else grant permission to your app and then test it.

Comment: but i think RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED is listed in automatic permissions so i dont need to ask for it ... just putting it in the manifist will solve the problem

Comment: If you want me to help than grant all permission to app if you can't figure out how to grant permission than grant permission from setting temporarily

Comment: Change this .BootReciever to BootReciever it may work now just remove the .

Comment: iam sorry for taking all this time :) i updated the post

Comment: Why did you use this in name .Services.Azkar_Services try using this Azkar_Services without adding dot before name and first start the application and after that reboot the device.

Comment: Are you first opening the app and after that rebooting the phone.

Comment: it will not work if i did that....the point is its working on the api that less tna  23 but bigger than that or equal to it no